# jQuery delegate not firing on dynamically created table

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that resides in my .js file

```
//This is the row highlighting for the results table
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table").delegate('td', 'mouseover mouseleave', function (e) {
        if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
            $(this).parent().addClass("hover");

        } else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass("hover");
        }
    });
});
```

It basically adds and removes a style to a table row.
This works perfectly for tables that are created are runtime.

However for tables that are dynamically created it doesn't do a thing.
This is how a table is being created.

```
//This function is called from the homepage, it calls for XML to be passed and renders the table with
//Existing enquiries
function loadEnqData() {

//Display ajax load graphic
showLoading('.enqLoading');

//Build results table, ready to receive results.
$('.enqResults').append('<table id="enqTable" class="enqTable"><thead><tr><th>' + textlib.get('lblEnqDate') + '</th><th>' + textlib.get('lblEnqUser') + '</th><th>' + textlib.get('lblEnqClientName') + '</th><th>' + textlib.get('lblEnqDetails') + '</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>');

//URL for XML data
var strURL = "enqData.aspx";
if (debug) {
    $.jGrowl('url= ' + strURL);
}
//Ajax call
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: strURL,
    dataType: "xml",
    timeout: 30000,
    success: function (xml) {
        //process XML results for each xml node
        $(xml).find('row').each(function () {

            if (debug) {
                $.jGrowl('Returned id of ' + $(this).attr('id'));
            }

            //Set data variables
            var strEnqID = $.trim($(this).attr('id'));
            var strEnqDate = $.trim($(this).attr('DateTimeLogged'));
            var strEnqClient = $.trim($(this).attr('Client_Name'));
            var strEnqDetails = $.trim($(this).attr('Work_Details'));
            var strEnqUsername = $.trim($(this).attr('username'));

            //Add in a data row to the results table.
            $('#enqTable > tbody:last').append('<tr onclick="selectEnq(\'' + strEnqID + '\');"><td>' + strEnqDate + '</td><td>' + strEnqUsername + '</td><td>' + strEnqClient + '</td><td>' + strEnqDetails + '</td></tr>');
        });
        //Tidy up
        $('.enqLoading').empty();

        //Enable sorting
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#enqTable").tablesorter();
        }
    );
        //Catch errors
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $.jGrowl("Error Please contact IT support - " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + " " + XMLHttpRequest.status + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown, { sticky: true });

    }
});


}
```

To summarise, this function creates a new table in my enqResults div, runs an ajax query, and adds rows to the tbody of the table with this code
     $('#enqTable > tbody:last').append

Why can delegate not bind to these elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of your code it appears you are appending the `table` element dynamically too - this is the problem. The primary selector of the `delegate()` method must be a static element - ie, one that is present on page load, and for the entire life of the page.

I can see you are appending your table to the `.enqResults` element, with that in mind, try this:

```
//This is the row highlighting for the results table
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".enqResults").delegate('table td', 'mouseover mouseleave', function (e) {
        if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
            $(this).parent().addClass("hover");

        } else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass("hover");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ahhh, that's the missing bit of knowledge. I was assuming that the primary selector could be dynamic. Good work, thanks.