# Strange behaviour of jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am attaching an event to all elements with classname of `element` inside the `main` container like below

```
$('#main').delegate('.element','click', function(){
     console.log($(this).html());
});
```

But the problem is the click event is fired when double click in Windows Chrome browser and in Mac it is fired with single click.

Browser : Google Chrome
OS tested : Windows8 and Mac
jQuery version : jQuery 1.10.2

Comment: Can you post your markup too?

Comment: Does it fire twice with a double click, or once?

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9DQU6/1/

Comment: @DerFlatulator It raising single time with double click.

Comment: Use .on instead of .delegate as of Version 1.7 of jQuery. See additional notes on http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: I have used on many times but failed so many times with dynamically added elements.

Comment: @Exception .on fails on dynamic elements when you don't specify a wrapper/container. $(window).on(etc...) will always work on dynamic content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery delegate not firing on dynamically created table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295800/jquery-delegate-not-firing-on-dynamically-created-table)

Comment: the important point here is the **dynamically created elements**

Comment: You should try to replicate your issue in a jsfiddle. If you are not able to replicate it, then your problem comes from somewhere else, not provided code.

Comment: @A.Wolff Will post a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).delegate('.element','click', function(){
     console.log($(this).html());
});
```

instead

```
$('#main').delegate('.element','click', function(){
     console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

From the [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) docs :

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation. More information on event binding and delegation is in the .on() method. In general, these are the equivalent templates for the two methods:

Try using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) :

```
$('#main').on('click','.element', function(){
     console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: @A.Wolff _supposed_ doesn't refer to certainty :)

Comment: Thats true, i should have said: delegate() works too for sure! ;) OP's issue is not there

Comment: No, it actually does work. on is more efficient than delegate, hence it's deprecation. I'd be **very** surprised if this fixed it

Comment: @A.Wolff There you go :D Anyway taking a wild guess at what the problem is, as far as i m concerned delegate still works, arun's fiddle confirms it.

Comment: @Liam Need more details from the OP to be able to say what the problem is. But with his current code/information all i can suspect is the delegate with jquery 1.10.